# Getting to POSE mode in 2.77a

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, pose-mode

How, pray tell, are you able to get to POSE MODE in Blender version 2.77a? I've imported a free, rigged model I downloaded to practice animating, but cannot get to this mode. CTRL + TAB does not work. Help please!

Comment: Try the dropdown with the name "Object mode" in the bottom of the 3D View. Select "Pose mode". Of course, the object must be posable.

Comment: Thanks, Gunslinger. I tried the object mode drop down menu. Pose mode is not there. If the object is not posable, shouldn't pose mode still show up? If not, that may be the problem. This is an .obj model (which I think originated in 3D Max), and I have discovered that this is not the rigged version. The rigged version is a .max file, which Blender does not read. Might then the answer be that I have to rig the model first, before pose mode is viable?

Comment: A hint, try using the rigify addon (if you are rigging a humanoid). When you have problems with it, come back here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will toggle pose mode if an object of type 'ARMATURE' is selected, or it will toggle weight paint if an object of type 'MESH' is selected.

Otherwise, you can select the armature in your 3D View (or outliner), then select *pose mode* from the menu in the header.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Timaroberts. I think the problem is, as I recently discovered,  that the model is not rigged after all. I am supposing this precludes the ability to see (e.g., through the object mode drop down menu), much less get into pose mode . Am I right about that?

Comment: @Anthony yes, pose mode is only available on armature objects.

Answer (score 0):

Select the armature in the outliner panel and this should give you pose mode when you change from object or edit mode.[image]